# Images disappearing when using Flex

Tags: react-native, flexbox

Simple issue: Whenever I use flex on an image it simply doesn't show up when I preview my app on expo.

This is the way I'm doing it:

```
            <Image 
                style = {{flex: 1, height: undefined, width: undefined}}
                source = {require('./img/anyImage.png')}
            />
```

If I just define the height and width, no flex, they show up. Is there any particular reason as to why my images aren't showing up?

Note: I've tried giving set values to both height and width.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

passing null instead of undefined should do the trick for you.

```
 <Image 
                    style = {{flex: 1, height: null, width: null}}
                    source = {require('./img/anyImage.png')}
                />
```

---

According to your code you can use one of these two options if you want to use flex.

1.giving the `flex:1` to the image with null width for taking the whole view

2.use flex with `resizeMode` for taking the whole view

```
{/* THIS IS THE FIRST OPTION YOU CAN USE  */}
        <View>
          <View style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}>
            <Image
              style={{ flex: 1, width: null }}
              source={require("./img/cervecerias.png")}
            />
          </View>
        </View>



    {/* THIS IS THE SECOND OPTION YOU CAN USE  */}
    <View style={{ width: 200, height: 100 }}>
      <Image
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        source={require("./img/Cocktails.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
      <Text style={styles.categoriesText}> Cocktails</Text>
    </View>
```

Comment: Hey, tried using null and it's still not working. I've just noticed if I try to add flex to a Text component, that doesn't work either. Do I need to import something or maybe it's just a weird issue?

Comment: if you push your codes to github and leave a link here it will be great

Comment: https://github.com/larguelles/imagesdisappearing that's the link to the repo. Thanks a lot!

Comment: note: the code I uploaded is not currently using flex. I changed it to fixed width and height so I could continue working. Another issue that popped up is that my images are also disappearing when I wrap them in a TouchableOpacity component.

Comment: i am editing my answer according to the codes you sent

Comment: This seems to be working, but what is the difference with what I was using technically speaking? I mean, could you please explain so I can apply this throughout all my code? Thanks!

Comment: no need to use display:"flex" ,that wont make sense that much in react native.

Comment: some of your style was blocking flex and overriding it. i change your code after you see them you will understand the problem, you can change the `View` to `TouchableOpacity`

Comment: i hope it helped, dont forget to upvote and mark as answer

Comment: Thank you so, so much, you have really just saved my life. I am absolutely grateful to you. f

Comment: your welcome dear @LuisArgüelles ,it is my pleasure . i am gonna start a new info series on ig , if you want to review your info and learn something new you can follow 'couple_bl0g' on ig

Comment: of course I will, it's the least I can do. Thanks a lot again!